# Excel: parsing columns to rows

Tags: excel, parsing, rows, data-cleaning

I have a database in the format:

```
Username|Email |First Name|Last Name|
Tom     |------|----------|---------|
--------|Tom@--|----------|---------|
--------|------|Tom-------|---------|
--------|------|----------|Brown----|
James---|------|----------|---------|
--------|James@|----------|---------|
```

And would like to parse it to the format:

```
Username|Email |First Name|Last Name|
Tom     |Tom@--|Tom-------|Brown----|
James---|James@|----------|---------|
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about achieving this, I've read some techniques using VBA and arrays but they don't appear to resolve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where you have run into problems.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is in Sheet1 and the first piece of data starts at A2, copy this into Sheet2, cell A1 and copy across and down.

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,(COLUMN(A1)-1)+4*(ROW(A1)-1),COLUMN(A1)-1)
```

Once the data has copied across, you might want to copy and paste-values to fix the data in place (it will remove the formula). You can then delete Sheet1. However, if you want to continue to add data to sheet1, then don't do this step, just leave the formula in place.

[image: A picture showing input text and output text on the same sheet]

Comment: produces mostly cells with `0` instead of what op asked for

Comment: I tested it in Excel and it worked fine with me.I just updated the formula as the data starts in A2 rather than A1.

Comment: Okay, with the updated formula I get 'Tom, James' in A and 0s everywhere else

Comment: @RobAnthony - Works for me +1, why don't you add a screen shot in answer for reference.

Comment: @RobAnthony - You can make your formula as `=IF(your_formula = 0,"",your_formula)` to avoid `0's` thought it makes formula look ugly.

Comment: You can but I don't get 0's at all, otherwise I would.

Comment: @RobAnthony - Drag/Copy down your formula further, you'll get zeros.

Comment: @RobAnthony - Delete *Williams* in `Cell D17`, you should get `0` in `Cell J4`

Comment: You are right, you will eventually get zeros and, if this is an issue, then use the modification you suggested. I had not done that as I assumed it was a one-off conversion and you would only copy the formula as far as you needed it.